# A 4x4 grid of red?

Tags: grid-deduction, steganography

[image: Screenshot of the grid.]

How is this 4x4 grid of red, colored? The only hint I'll give is that

> $a = 97$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First we notice that:

> Every square is colored with R=n+100, G=n, B=n where n is some integer
>  [image: Labeled square]

Then we realize that

> n is not arbitrary integers, but ASCII values. Converting to ASCII, we get the following word square:
>
> ```
> arcs
> real
> cave
> sled
> ```

In response, I anagram the solution:

> Lad-clear crevasse

Comment: Solved without the hint but took my time anagramming ;(